# Is it possible to block internet browsing, but not the LAN, without admin privileges?

Tags: windows-7, networking, administrator

I'm trying to block internet browsing through all browsers (IE, Firefox, and Chrome) on my Windows 7 workstation, while still maintaining access to my network drives. The instructions I've found say to do this through the Network and Sharing Center -> Local Area Connection -> Properties dialog, but that requires admin privileges. I'm interested in doing this only for my user account, but I haven't found a way yet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Right now I can't think of any way to cut off the Internet connection without admin privileges, since anything related with networking usually requires them.

However, a possibility could be unplugging the phone/fiber cord from your router, so it can't connect to the outside world, but still keeping up your local network.

Comment: Hmmm, ok. I don't have access to the router in this case, since it's in an office environment, but I'll keep looking.